# How to execute multiple commands to a variable in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I am trying to make a cleaning function for some data:

```
clean=function(x){
x[-(1:2),]
x[-(1604:1658),]
names(x)=c(1,2)
}
```

The goal is to delete the first and second, along with the 1604th-1658th rows, and rename the headers to `1` and `2`. Unfortunately, when I run this `[x=clean(x)]`, it just deletes all my data and replaces it with one column and two rows, the first of which is 1 and the second of which is 2. What is going on?

Comment: `clean = function(x) setNames(x[-c(1:2,1604:1658),],1:2)`

Comment: fwiw better to not name a column with a number only. Why not `col1` or `c1`?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is all messed up:

```
clean <- function(x){
    x = x[-c(1:2,1604:1658),]
    colnames(x) = c("Col1", "Col2")
    return(x)
}
```

Added a `return` statement per @Pierre's suggestion